# Como usa-se a diretiva .run do Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Como se usa a diretiva `.run` do AngularJS?

Comment: Como norma básica, considero de má-qualidade uma pergunta cujo texto é exatamente igual ao título. E, relembrando, saudações e agradecimentos são considerados ***ruido***: vide *"Não tem bla bla bla"* no **[tour]**

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = angular.module('aplicacao', ['highcharts-ng']);

app.run(function($rootScope) {
    ...     
});
```

Explicando:

```
  var app = angular.module('aplicacao', ['highcharts-ng']);
```

Cria um módulo angular chamado 'aplicacao' que injeta a dependência de 'highcharts-ng'.

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
```

É o ponto de partida da sua aplicação. Como comparação, é igual ao main(args) do java/c#.

E dentro dele você irá escrever seu código com as funções desejadas (:

Comment: Certo Pedro,
Mas e se você quiser iniciar uma variavel global nela? Dentro da função?

Comment: Através do $rootScope, como pode ser feito em qualquer outro serviço, controller, etc..

Comment: Declare dentro de app.run(function() { sua variável global como qualquer outra variável em Javascript (var i = 0;)